# postgresql on windows won't install with data and executables on different disks

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, windows-server

I am trying to install postgresql 9.4.4 on a windows 2008 rc2 machine that has 2 HDs.
The first HD is, in theory, used only for executables/code/etc while the second one, being faster, should be used for data.

When I try to install postgresql the only way in which I can get an installation is if I select to put postgresql's exec and data on the same disk (the exec one). If I decide, as I want, to install postgresql "split" (with the 'data' directory on the second disk) the installation tells me that the cluster could not be initialized.

How can I solve this? I think it's related to some setting in Windows 2008 but I don't know what or which.

Ideas or pointers or RTFMs? :)

(I have noticed other similar questions but they don't apply in this case....)

Thanks!

Comment: Is the second disk FAT32 or exFAT formatted? PostgreSQL will not run on exFAT or FAT32 because they cannot be made reliably crash-safe. Otherwise, please get the installer log file and show any relevant parts here (or upload the whole thing and post a link here). See also: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Troubleshooting_Installation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not with Postgresql, but rather with the permissions on the second disk.

Enabling the relevant users to write on the disk (at the disk level) solved the situation.

Sorry for the noise, but I thought to post an answer, since it appears this kind of problem has fooled quite a bit of people on the Net. :)